# Hibernate - Saving an ArrayList "as is" to MySQL using JPA Repository

Tags: hibernate

I have an array that will have an unknown number of objects in the array.

```
[
   {
      "individualorentity":{
         "individualorentity":"Individual (SSN / Other)"
      },
      "filloutapplicationmain":{
         "firstname":"Channing",
         "lastname":"Tatum",
         "dateofbirth":"1986-01-01",
         "month":"01",
         "day":"01",
         "year":1986,
         "street1":"123 Main Street",
         "street2":"",
         "city":"Beverly Hills",
         "state":"California",
         "zip":"90210",
         "email":"CTatum@gmail.com",
         "phone":"9999999999",
         "citizenship":"I am not a US citizen"
      },
      "residentialorcommercial":{
         "residentialorcommercial":"residential"
      },
      "selectproperty":{
         "street1":"123 Main Street",
         "city":"Hollywood",
         "state":"CA",
         "zip":"90210",
         "property":"1"
      },
      "moveindate":{
         "moveindate":"2020-10-11",
         "month":"10",
         "day":"11",
         "year":2020
      },
      "ownorrent":{
         "ownorrent":"Own",
         "currency":"0",
         "rangeoftime":"1-2 Years"
      },
      "assets":{
         "currency":"0"
      },
      "requireddocumentation":{
         "identification":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "socialsecuritycard":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "proofofresidency":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "bankstatements":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "leasemortgagestatement":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "proofofincome":[
            
         ],
         "assets":[
            
         ],
         "taxreturns":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "references":[
            
         ],
         "additionaldocuments":[
            
         ]
      },
      "paymentdetails":{
         "month":"01",
         "year":2021,
         "creditcardcvc":"000",
         "creditcardexpirationdate":"2021-01",
         "creditcardnumber":"4242424242424242"
      },
      "confirmation":{
         "acknowledgementcheckboxes":[
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
         ],
         "signature":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
         "todaysdate":"2020-10-11",
         "month":"10",
         "year":2020,
         "day":"11"
      }
   },
   {
      "individualorentity":{
         "individualorentity":"Individual (SSN / Other)"
      },
      "filloutapplicationmain":{
         "firstname":"Channing",
         "lastname":"Tatum",
         "dateofbirth":"1986-01-01",
         "month":"01",
         "day":"01",
         "year":1986,
         "street1":"123 Main Street",
         "street2":"",
         "city":"Beverly Hills",
         "state":"California",
         "zip":"90210",
         "email":"CTatum@gmail.com",
         "phone":"9999999999",
         "citizenship":"I am not a US citizen"
      },
      "ownorrent":{
         "ownorrent":"Own",
         "currency":"0",
         "rangeoftime":"1-2 Years"
      },
      "assets":{
         "currency":"0"
      },
      "requireddocumentation":{
         "identification":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "socialsecuritycard":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "proofofresidency":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "bankstatements":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "leasemortgagestatement":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "proofofincome":[
            
         ],
         "assets":[
            
         ],
         "taxreturns":[
            {
               "name":"Whatever",
               "dataurl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
               "type":"png"
            }
         ],
         "references":[
            
         ],
         "additionaldocuments":[
            
         ]
      },
      "paymentdetails":{
         "month":"01",
         "year":2021,
         "creditcardcvc":"000",
         "creditcardexpirationdate":"2021-01",
         "creditcardnumber":"4242424242424242"
      },
      "confirmation":{
         "acknowledgementcheckboxes":[
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
         ],
         "signature":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=",
         "todaysdate":"2020-10-11",
         "month":"10",
         "year":2020,
         "day":"11"
      }
   }
]
```

```
@Repository
public interface applicationrepository extends JpaRepository<applications, Long> {}

@RestController
public class newapplications {
    @Autowired applicationrepository applicationrepository;
    @PostMapping("/v1/newapplications")
    public void createvisitor(@RequestBody applications applications) {}
}

@Entity
public class applications {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "applications", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<application> applications;
}
```

Why am I getting this compile error?

```
Could not resolve parameter [0] in public void
com.demo.v1.tenantapplications.controller.newapplications.createvisitor(com.demo.v1.tenantapplications.domain.applications):
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
`com.demo.v1.tenantapplications.domain.applications`
out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot deserialize instance of
`com.demo.v1.tenantapplications.domain.applications`
out of START_ARRAY token
```

I don't have any control on what comes down for the JSON, I just need to "deserialize" it to proper format, but just not understanding it.

I ultimately need to get this to the database and be able to query all these datapoints.

Comment: `applications` is an object. Your JSON is an array. You cannot deserialize an array into an object that is not a collection. You need your JSON to reflect the structure of the type to deserialize onto, i.e. `{ "applications": [...]}`

Comment: @Crizzis I follow you on the first part "applications is an object. Your JSON is an array. You cannot deserialize an array into an object that is not a collection" makes complete sense. Although, if I can't change the JSON coming down what would this look like?

Comment: Ummm... `@RequestBody List<application> applications`, I suppose

Comment: And I assume that I would then need to update the repository with the same `List<application>` but when I did that, I got `Error creating bean with name 'applicationrepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface java.util.List`

Comment: My comment dealt with a proper declaration of the controller method so that the JSON gets consumed without errors. How you *then* map the received list onto entities is a completely separate matter. I cannot help without knowing what the requirements are, but surely, `Repository<List<application>, ...>` will not work, because `List<appliction>` is not an entity

Comment: Hopefully this makes sense...I updated the JSON to show the real JSON that is coming down (I was trying to make it an easily readable question). I am not sold on any specific table layout (I guess whatever is easiest), but ultimately I want to be able to query all these datapoints later on in the JSON (so I think things like `@ElementCollection` and `@Embedded` are off the table), so I turn to `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne` (I think). That being said, if I need to create a ton of tables for all this that is fine, I just need a solution that works at this point, and I can refine it later.

Comment: The problem is I still do not quite understand how you expect the update endpoint to work. Is it supposed to replace all previous `application`s with a completely different list? In that case, just use the `CrudRepository<application, ...>`'s `saveAll()` and `deleteAll()` methods. Or, if you want the new list to be merged with the existing list, using `saveAll()` should be enough (which property is the `application`'s id, by the way?)